# "Done" button for ionic selection disppeared. ionic1 on ionic3 environment

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, plugins, keyboard, ionic3

I am using ionic 1 code and my environment is now ionic 3. For some reason "Done" button disappeared for all my selections.

Here is a screenshot of the selection but without the "Done" button. It used to have "Done" button. this is the problem screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/38HgA.jpg, it used to be good like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jdzzj.jpg.

controller.js

```
  // select options for visitor type
  visitor_types_approval_json = JSON.parse(window.localStorage['visitor_types_approval_json']);
  $scope.visitor_types_items = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < visitor_types_approval_json.visitor_types.length; ++i) {
    $scope.visitor_types_items.push(visitor_types_approval_json.visitor_types[i].typename);
  };
```

template html for selection

```
<label class="item item-input item-select">
    <div class="input-label">
      {{'VISITORS_TYPE_OF_VISITOR'|translate}}
    </div>
    <select ng-model="data.visitorType">
        <option ng-repeat="visitor_types_item in visitor_types_items" value="{{visitor_types_item}}">{{visitor_types_item}}</option>
    </select>
  </label>

<br>
```

config.xml

```
<plugin name="com.moust.cordova.videoplayer" spec="https://github.com/moust/cordova-plugin-videoplayer" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-app-version" spec="https://github.com/whiteoctober/cordova-plugin-app-version.git" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-file-transfer" spec="~1.5.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-image-picker" spec="https://github.com/mirulumam/cordova-imagePicker" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="~3.1.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="~1.2.1" />
<plugin name="onesignal-cordova-plugin" spec="~1.12.5" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera" spec="^2.4.1">
    <variable name="CAMERA_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" value=" " />
    <variable name="PHOTOLIBRARY_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" value=" " />
</plugin>
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" spec="^1.7.2" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-actionsheet" spec="^2.3.3" />
<plugin name="ionic-plugin-keyboard" spec="^2.2.1" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-network-information" spec="^1.3.4" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="^1.1.7" />
<engine name="ios" spec="4.5.4" />
```

my environment

```
ionic version 3.19.1
cordova version 8.0.0
npm version 5.6.0
macos High Sierra 10.13.1
xcode 9.2
```

Im curious, is it something to do with my keyboard plugin ? Need to get the "Done" button back for selection. Thanks.

Comment: probably i got it fixed by cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(false); and npm install npm -g

Comment: Therefore, it's a duplicate question. Please mark the comment as useful for future references @Axil .